# Merging C# code in Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I got the code of detecting poor grammar from here - [Detecting Poor grammar](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1179799/Coding-challenge-detect-poor-grammar)

I am new to C# and Xamarin. I want to merge this code into my speech to text conversion app.

I tried to do it, but I am not getting the desired results.

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Speech;
using Android.Util;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

namespace SpeechToText
{
    [Activity(Label = "SpeechToText", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity, IRecognitionListener
    {
        public const string Tag = "VoiceRec";

        SpeechRecognizer Recognizer { get; set; }
        Intent SpeechIntent { get; set; }
        TextView Label { get; set; }
        TextView Label1 { get; set; }

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            Recognizer = SpeechRecognizer.CreateSpeechRecognizer(this);
            Recognizer.SetRecognitionListener(this);

            SpeechIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ActionRecognizeSpeech);
            SpeechIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraLanguageModel, RecognizerIntent.LanguageModelFreeForm);
            SpeechIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraCallingPackage, PackageName);

            var button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btn);
            button.Click += ButtonClick;

            var Grammarbutton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btn1);
            Grammarbutton.Click += new EventHandler(ButtonClick2);

            Label = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tv);
            Label1 = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tv1);
        }

        private void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Recognizer.StartListening(SpeechIntent);
        }

        public void OnResults(Bundle results)
        {
            var matches = results.GetStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.ResultsRecognition);
            if (matches != null && matches.Count > 0)
            {
                Label.Text = matches[0];
            }

        }

        private void ButtonClick2(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var api = new GingerItApi();
            for (; ; )
            {
                Console.Write("Text to check: ");
                var text = Label.Text;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)) break;

                try
                {
                    var result = api.Check(text);
                    if (result?.Corrections?.Count != 0)
                    {

                        for (int i = 0; i < result.Corrections.Count; i++)
                        {
                            var item = result.Corrections[i];
                            var mistakes = string.Join(", ", item.Mistakes.Select(x => $"\"{text.Substring(x.From, x.To - x.From + 1)}\""));
                            var suggestions = string.Join(", ", item.Suggestions.Select(x => $"\"{x.Text}\""));
                            Label1.Text = $"  {i + 1}: {mistakes} >> {suggestions}";
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Looks okay.\n");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"**Error: {ex.Message}\n");
                }

            }
        }

        public void OnReadyForSpeech(Bundle @params)
        {
            Log.Debug(Tag, "OnReadyForSpeech");
        }

        public void OnBeginningOfSpeech()
        {
            Log.Debug(Tag, "OnBeginningOfSpeech");
        }

        public void OnEndOfSpeech()
        {
            Log.Debug(Tag, "OnEndOfSpeech");
        }

        public void OnError([GeneratedEnum] SpeechRecognizerError error)
        {
            Log.Debug("OnError", error.ToString());
        }

        public void OnBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) { }

        public void OnEvent(int eventType, Bundle @params) { }

        public void OnPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) { }

        public void OnRmsChanged(float rmsdB) { }
    }
}

class GingerItApi
        {
            public CheckResult Check(string text)
            {
                var request = WebRequest.Create($"https://services.gingersoftware.com/Ginger/correct/jsonSecured/GingerTheTextFull?callback=jQuery172015406464511272344_1490987331365&apiKey=GingerWebSite&lang=US&clientVersion=2.0&text={text}&_=1490987518060") as HttpWebRequest;
                WebResponse response = null;
                try
                {
                    response = request.GetResponse();

                    if (response != null)
                    {
                        using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                        {
                            string data = reader.ReadToEnd();
                            var first = data.IndexOf('{');
                            var last = data.LastIndexOf('}');
                            var json = data.Substring(first, last - first + 1);
                            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CheckResult>(json);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    throw;
                }
                return null;
            }
        }

        public class LrnFrgOrigIndx
        {
            [JsonProperty("From")]
            public int From { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("To")]
            public int To { get; set; }
        }

        public class Mistake
        {
            [JsonProperty("Definition")]
            public string Definition { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("CanAddToDict")]
            public bool CanAddToDict { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("From")]
            public int From { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("To")]
            public int To { get; set; }
        }

        public class Suggestion
        {
            [JsonProperty("Definition")]
            public string Definition { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("LrnCatId")]
            public int LrnCatId { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("Text")]
            public string Text { get; set; }
        }

        public class Correction
        {
            [JsonProperty("Confidence")]
            public int Confidence { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("From")]
            public int From { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("LrnFrg")]
            public string LrnFrg { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("LrnFrgOrigIndxs")]
            public IList<LrnFrgOrigIndx> LrnFrgOrigIndxs { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("Mistakes")]
            public IList<Mistake> Mistakes { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("ShouldReplace")]
            public bool ShouldReplace { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("Suggestions")]
            public IList<Suggestion> Suggestions { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("To")]
            public int To { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("TopLrnCatId")]
            public int TopLrnCatId { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("Type")]
            public int Type { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("UXFrgFrom")]
            public int UXFrgFrom { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("UXFrgTo")]
            public int UXFrgTo { get; set; }
        }

        public class Sentence
        {
            [JsonProperty("FromIndex")]
            public int FromIndex { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("IsEnglish")]
            public bool IsEnglish { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("ToIndex")]
            public int ToIndex { get; set; }
        }

        public class CheckResult
        {
            [JsonProperty("Corrections")]
            public IList<Correction> Corrections { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("Sentences")]
            public IList<Sentence> Sentences { get; set; }
        }
```

I want to get the recognized speech, send it to grammar corrector, and display the output.

Please help me to solve this, or at least help me to further research the problem.

Thank you.

Comment: StackOverflow is not your personal code-refactoring service. Please read [ask]

Comment: Yes,I know. But I have no direction in which I can go ahead.That's why I asked the question.

Comment: Can anybody just tell me that how can I pass textof one TextView to another TextView.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have put an infinite loop in your code. Please remove it.

For example:

```
    private void ButtonClick2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var api = new GingerItApi();
        Console.Write("Text to check: ");
        var text = Label.Text;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
        {
            try
            {
                var result = api.Check(text);
                if (result?.Corrections?.Count != 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < result.Corrections.Count; i++)
                    {
                        var item = result.Corrections[i];
                        var mistakes = string.Join(", ", item.Mistakes.Select(x => $"\"{text.Substring(x.From, x.To - x.From + 1)}\""));
                        var suggestions = string.Join(", ", item.Suggestions.Select(x => $"\"{x.Text}\""));
                        Label1.Text = $"  {i + 1}: {mistakes} >> {suggestions}";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Label1.Text = "Looks okay.\n";
                    Console.WriteLine("Looks okay.\n");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"**Error: {ex.Message}\n");
            }
        }
    }
```

And the result is:
[image]